# EasyMock java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected method call

Tags: java, easymock

I am new to EasyMock and am stuck now. 
Can't I set the fields of mocked object?
Where am I going wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.

```
IService service = EasyMock.createMock(IService.class);
service.setName("abc"); 
EasyMock.replay(service);
org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("abc", service.getName());
EasyMock.verify(service);

    java.lang.AssertionError: 
      Unexpected method call getName():
        setName("abc"): expected: 1, actual: 0
        at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:45)
        at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:73)
        at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:92)
```

Comment: Why would you want to set the field of a **mock** object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to set the field using expect(..) of EasyMock.

Remove this line of code

```
service.setName("abc");
```

and add

```
EasyMock.expect(service.getName()).andReturn("abc");
```

Comment: What's the point of expecting a getter to return `X` and asserting if it does return `X` later? What are you testing: the working of your application or that of `Easymock`?

Comment: The issue was to set the field of mock object , which I required for further testing , I cannot paste the complete code here. My actual test was not asserting this value but my further assertions were failing as this field value was not set to what I required. I asserted the value in this example and found that  service.setName("abc");  does not set the value.